# VB.net Array of Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, integer

I've been searching for an example for array of arrays but I couldn't find any. Any link or explanation will be great.

What I'm really trying to do:
I have angles and edges of polygons and I want to insert those informations inside array, It looks like this at the time:

```
Dim edges() as integer
Dİm angles() as integer
??Dim ArrayOfArray as integer??

Private sub AddPolygonToArray
for i = 0 to x
edges(i) = edge
angles(i) = angle
next
??ArrayOfArray(index) = new Array(edges,angles,NameOfPolygon,QuantityOfPolygon)??
End Sub
```

- Index,nameofpolygon and quantityofpolygon are not necessary, but they're integers if you need to know.
  If anything is incomprhensible, don't be afraid to ask.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Resizing arrays is a Very Bad Idea.  Use a List(Of Polygon) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where will I keep Informations to draw the polygon, it'll be better if there's only one array instead of 4. Can you please explain what do you mean when saying list of polygon?

Comment: There's only one list.  Your Polygon class should have an Edge and Angle property.  This is covered well in any introductory book for VB.NET, pay a visit to your local library.

Comment: You are better off putting the information inside a class or a structure instead of having a multidimentional array.

Comment: I agree with Hans: this should be handled in a more object oriented way, since we have the tools available. I believe what you are asking for is a multidimensional array, which is unnecessary in this day in age. There are *rare* cases when it can be a good idea for raw performance (i.e. cryptography algorithms), but this doesn't appear to be one of those cases.

Comment: See [Creating Classes in Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx)  sort of an online local library for a great many things NET and VB related

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments, I'll better do that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of multidimensional Arrays

Regular multidimensional array

```
Dim mdArray(5, 5, 5) as integer
```

And Jugged Array (Array of Arrays)

```
Dim jugged()() as integer
```

Since geometry is all about 3 dimensions, I believe, you can describe any shape using 3-dimentional array such as `mdArray(5, 5, 5)`

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `List(Of Polygon)`.

But if you can't, you can always do a [Multidimensional Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx)

This means that you can do

```
Dim MultiArray(X,Y,Z,W)
```